# BigQuery costs structure

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have a table made out of 5M lines. I want to do a query on that table, and limit my search on 1 column, will every query take data from 5M rows (having i.e. 254bytes in each record, so doing about 254 * 5M bytes = 1GB for my quota?

Or will only the result be counted (say result is 100 rows)?

In the documentation I think the first, but it can get several TB's quite quickly then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows from the source are counted, but only from the columns referenced in the query. So the query

```
SELECT foo FROM table1 where bar = 3
```

will be billed for the # of rows in the table times the sum of the sizes of the foo and bar columns (even if the table has many more columns). Let's say the table is 5M rows, and foo is a string, with average length 10 chars, and bar is an integer. In this case, you'd be billed for access to `5M * ((10+2) + 8) = 100 MB`. (Strings get billed for their utf8-encoded length + 2 bytes).

Comment: Thank you.
But say, I need, foo, foo2, foo3 and foo4 where bar = 3,

Will it also count 5M * all foo's? 

Since I would need a LOT of info from 1 row once found, but I only have to check all rows for 'bar'.

Comment: Yes, if foo, foo2, foo3, and foo4 were all different columns, you'd need to scan the entire table for each row, even if 'bar' limited you to a single row. This is because in a column-oriented system, you need to walk all of the columns in parallel.